# Converting awt Math function to Android Math function

Tags: java, android, awt

I have some code written for the `awt` library. I want to port that to Android. But I'm not really sure hot to port a few methods.

Here is what I have so far. The part that is ***commented out*** is the original ***awt*** code. The part that is ***not*** commented out, is my new Android code.

I'm not sure if I can translate awt's `t.translate()` to Androids `t.postTranslate()`, along with some other lines of code. And I also don't know how to transport some other `awt` methods at all.

So I'm looking for an answer how to port the below code to Android equivalent functionality.

```
//AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
//Point2D.Float p = new Point2D.Float();
Matrix t = new Matrix();
PointF p = new PointF();


//t.setToIdentity();
//t.translate( cx+f*translateX, cy+f*translateY );

t.No Idea How To Set to Identity();
t.postTranslate(cx+f*translateX, cy+f*translateY);


//t.scale( s, s );
t.postScale( s, s );

//t.rotate( -rotation*f );
t.postRotate(-rotation*f);


//t.translate( -cx, -cy );
t.postTranslate(-cx, -cy);


//t.transform( p, p );
//t.mapPoints(p);
t.No Idea How TO Transform();
t.no Idea how to Map Pounts?();
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/5783624/2982225

Comment: @Payeli I dont want to port the entire awt lib to android or anything. I just want to know how to set a `Matrix` to an `identity` matrix for example. In awt I can do `.setToIdentity()`. But Android doesn't have to method on a `Matrix` object. So there must be some other way to do it. Since settings matrices to an identity matrix isn't uncommon at all.

Comment: @Vivendi I have a similar problem. Have you solved it? If yes, how?

Comment: @dritan I haven't solved it. I later moved on to an OpenGL solution.

Comment: @Vivendi I just found this link on the internet. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9066cfe9886ac131c34d59ed0e2d287b0e3c0087/awt/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.java 
But I cant't tell if it does the work.

Comment: I just realized that the link I posted above, is from a very old Android version. Apparently removed Google this package entirely in newer version of Android