# How can I import java.awt.image.BufferedImage in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bufferedimage

I need my android app to recognize BufferedImage and I am using Android Studio.
I've seen that there is a way to import JRE library system in Eclipse but I am having trouble doing so in Android Studio.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to use Android's own Bitmap class instead of the awt image.

Comment: Hi abbath, thank you for answering. I already have the implementation and I would rather not change my code if there is a way to import JRE

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you to change your implementation

Comment: But why? would importing jre library system raise other problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add java.awt.image package in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android)

Comment: @LaraLarsen Android isn't a Java virtual machine (although it is similar). So to import the `java.awt.*` classes, you would need to re-implement the low-level (native) parts of AWT... Doing this might not be entirely impossible, it's just *a lot* simpler to just use Android's `Bitmap` class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can't.**

The AWT package is not supported in Android, you need to change your implementation to use the Android classes.

See these similar questions:

[Porting AWT graphics code to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783624/porting-awt-graphics-code-to-android)

[How to add java AWT image package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android)

[Using AWT with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897775/using-awt-with-android)

Comment: Someone's tried to port it in, and failed. https://code.google.com/archive/p/awt-android-compat/