# Java error "BufferedImage cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm trying to use the BufferedImage datatype.
The normal path would be "java.awt.image.BufferedImage" but im finding only "java.awt".
I'm using eclipse 2021-09 as my IDE with the JDK11 version.

Comment: If you are developing for Android, then your question is answered by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210065.  If not, perhaps you have somehow managed to accidentally select / configure an Android "JDK"?   Or perhaps you need to reset your IDE?

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. :)
I dont develope for android. I created a "Dynamic Web Project" and I'm not sure if i missconfigure something.