# How to make reliase without error?

Tags: java, android, apache

It is a time to make first little reliase. During building process i got such error

> Information:Gradle tasks [:Application:assembleRelease]
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
>   Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
>   Warning:javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetContextPeer
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DragSourceContextPeer
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DirectColorModel
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferUShort
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.FlavorsComparator: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
>   Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
>   Warning:there were 247 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>   Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 18.423 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:110 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

and can't undestand how to fix them?

Could you help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: I guess sometimes an extract of your error messages might be good enough :-)

Comment: @GhostCat but how i can find usages of awt package? I can't find them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using the Apache Harmony library, which utilizes Java AWT.  The `java.awt` package is not part of Android.  You cannot use code or libraries which depend on the `java.awt` package.

```
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy.
can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
```

See also:

[How to add java.awt.image package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android)

[Using awt with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897775/using-awt-with-android)

[Porting AWT graphics code to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783624/porting-awt-graphics-code-to-android)

Comment: but how i can determine where within my project i use this package?because i don't remember that i connect this packege to my project...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Based on the error message, your using Apache Harmony.

Comment: No i don'y have such dependensis in my gradle file... and even i click `Ctrl+Shift+F` - global serching i don't find any matches...

Comment: How to exclude this pacage?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Unfortunately, its hard for me to say.  If its not a direct dependency, it may be a transitive one (a dependency of another dependency).