# How to exclude AWT package from my project?

Tags: java, android, awt

During building i got error because i use some awt pacage in my project. But i can't find where exactly i use it...

There is a mistake that i get

> Information:Gradle tasks [:Application:assembleRelease] Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback

Who i can find usages and delete them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on you IDE, sometimes you can use a "Find Usages" tool, that lets you find places where a class, a method or a property has been used. In Netbeans, you find it the Edit menu or using Alt+F7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make reliase without error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450121/how-to-make-reliase-without-error)

Comment: @bracco23 No I have already tried it